# Avoid bundled jquery in Yii

Tags: jquery, yii

I read a book called "Yii Application development cookbook" which has a chapter that includes these lines:

> "Sometimes, you need to suppress including a bundled jQuery. For
>   example, if your project code relies on version specific
>   functionality. ..."

Can you help me understand the two questions below:

1. What exactly is "bundled jQuery" (My first understanding is that it's just some javascript code using jQuery framework. I'm not sure whether I'm right or not)
2. What is the author's purpose when he writes "relies on version specific functionality", does he mean to force Yii application to use only one version of jQuery and not upgrade to the most latest if it becomes obsolete?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yii comes with a default jQuery version bundled with it, this is the bundled jQuery he means, the actual "version" of jQuery (1.2, 1.3... 1.7, 1.8 etc), not just some code using it. So when you call jQuery in your default Yii install Yii will initiate the jQuery version that's bundled with it, which may not necessarily be the most recent jQuery version, depending on what version of Yii you have and what version of jQuery was bundled with that Yii version.

2) If, for example, the version of Yii you have came bundled with jQuery version 1.7 and you have some code that relies on a feature of jQuery that's only in jQuery version 1.8, then you'd need to suppress the default bundled version (1.7) and use a version you specify (1.8 in this example).